# Наследование в c# без ссылок на поля

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Есть класс от которого наследуются несколько других.
Он содержит: динамическое поле, статическое поле, конструктор, динамический метод.

```
class Parent
{
    public int num;
    public static string text;

    public Parent(int num)
    {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void Method() { #dosomething }
}

class Child1 : Parent
{
    public Child1(int num) : base(num) { } 
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    public Child2(int num) : base(num) { } 
}
```

Если я попробую изменить поле text в одном из детей, то изменится поле у родителя.
Как мне сделать чтобы они не ссылались на Родителя а имели каждый собственное поле?

```
Child1.text = "qwe";
Child2.text = "123";
```

Comment: Только что мне написали ответ что нужно убрать static.
А что если мне нельзя каждый раз создавать экземпляр класса?
Мне нужно чтобы это поле текст я мог достать в любой момент в программе.

Comment: Да я уже понял, что это не совсем то, что вам нужно, надо ещё подумать...

Comment: Спасибо большое что помогаете)

Comment: Написал другой вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто перекройте в классах-наследниках родительское поле `text`:

```
class Child1 : Parent
{
    public static new string text;
    public Child1(int num) : base(num) { } 
}

class Child2 : Parent
{
    public static new string text;
    public Child2(int num) : base(num) { } 
}
```

Только нужно добавить ключевое слово `new`, иначе компилятор сомневается - намеренно ли было сделано перекрытие или случайно.

Comment: Это работает. Большое спасибо.

Comment: это не будет работать, если использовать приведение типов `Parent child = new Child1(); child.text = 10;`